# Idiomatic way to express a polynomial in terms of a shifted variable

Tags: polynomials, algebraic-manipulation

I have a polynomial of known degree, $f(x) = \sum_{n = 0}^N a_n x^n$ and I' d like to express it in terms of a shifted variable $x - x_ 0$, so that $f(x) = \sum_{n = 0}^N b_n (x - x_ 0)^n$.

I can do this by hand on paper, and I have a round about way of achieving the same result in Mathematica, but I' m pretty sure there has to be a standard name for the procedure I' m following when doing it manually. The round about way I currently use exploits the Taylor series, and goes like this:

```
Normal[Series[1 + x + x^6, {x, x0, 6}]]
Simplify[Normal[Series[1 + x + x^6, {x, x0, 6}]]] == 1 + x + x^6
```

Is there a more compact way of achieving this?

Comment: Check [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/77842/efficient-algorithm-to-translate-shift-polynomials).

Comment: Interesting; however, that post is a close, but different, problem. I merely want a re-expression of the same function. To take their example, I want $f(x) = x^2$ to be expressed in the form $f(x) = (x+1)^2 - 2(x+1) +1$. That is, I want the polynomial in $x$ to be expressed as  polynomial in $(x+1)$.

Comment: But are they not basically inverses? So you could use that on x-1 instead of x+1, that is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's more compact, but just for the sake of it, here's another way:

```
Collect[Expand[1 + x + x^6 /. x :> xdiff + x0], xdiff] /. xdiff :> x - x0
```

If you want it organized, apply `HoldForm` after evaluating `Collect`, but before replacing `xdiff`, which can be, for example, achieved with

```
HoldForm @@ {Collect[Expand[1 + x + x^6 /. x :> xdiff + x0], xdiff]} /. xdiff :> x - x0
```

This relies on `xdiff` being clear, so you may want to package it in a function which keeps your variables fresh, and which gives you the option to hold the form or not as an optional fourth argument (false by default here):

```
PolynomialShift[poly_, x_Symbol, x0_, hold : (True | False) : False] := 
 Module[{xdiff}, 
  If[hold, HoldForm, Identity]
    @@ {Collect[Expand[poly /. x :> xdiff + x0], xdiff]} /. xdiff :> x - x0]

(* E.g. *)

 In[1]:=  PolynomialShift[1 + x + x^6, x, x0]
Out[1]:=  1 + (x - x0)^6 + x0 + 6 (x - x0)^5 x0 + 15 (x - x0)^4 x0^2 + 
            20 (x - x0)^3 x0^3 + 15 (x - x0)^2 x0^4 + x0^6 + (x - x0) (1 + 6 x0^5)

 In[2]:=  PolynomialShift[1 + x + x^6, x, x0, True]
Out[2]:=  1 + x0 + x0^6 + (1 + 6 x0^5) (x - x0) + 15 x0^4 (x - x0)^2 + 
            20 x0^3 (x - x0)^3 + 15 x0^2 (x - x0)^4 + 6 x0 (x - x0)^5 + (x - x0)^6
```

If you don't care about the ordering, though,

```
PolynomialShift[poly_, x_Symbol, x0_] :=
  Normal[Series[poly, {x, x0, Exponent[poly, x]}]
```

is probably the most compact you'll get.